# What is "stick" button on windows in xfce?

Tags: xfce, window, window-management

In xfwm4-settings I found "stick" button and I can't understand what does this button. I think that it will stick the current window to another, but this button does not do it. So what does this button is supposed to do?

[image: xfwm4-settings window]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it's supposed to stick the window to the screen, making it visible on all workspaces.